# Alignment of fundamental type and structure with only this fundamental type inside

Tags: c++, alignment

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
   double a;
};

int main(){
   std::cout << alignof(A) << std::endl; // prints 4
   std::cout << alignof(double) << std::endl; // prints 8
   return 0;
}
```

Why alignment of structure `A` and raw `double` type is different? I'm using Linux 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a possible explanation here: [Implementation of alignof](http://www.wambold.com/Martin/writings/alignof.html)

> Amazing facts about alignment
>
> On modern x86 processors, the type double is most efficiently aligned at multiples of 8. And in fact, gcc aligns "free" doubles at multiples of 8 within stack frames. Unfortunately, ancient ABIs require that the alignment of a double within a struct is 4. The unexpected consequence is that, on x86 Linux, gcc has
>
> ```
>   struct Double { double d; };
>   __alignof__ (double) == 8
>   __alignof__ (Double) == 4;
> ```
>
> The same ancient ABIs specify that the size of long double is 12. Because the alignment must be a factor of the size, we have the curious situation that:
>
> ```
>   __alignof__ (double) == 8
>   __alignof__ (long double) == 4;
> ```
>
> even though long double "wants" to be at least as aligned as double.
>
> Fortunately, it doesn't matter very much, because we never care about the alignment of types that aren't struct members.